# making a selected font in the console to default

Tags: fonts

Please bear with me am a newbie.I have run "dpkg-reconfigure console-setup" in order to change the font. Am wondering if there is any way to configure my font size to be the fixed. What happens on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, when I change the console(tty) font size is that after rebooting my machine, the font goes back to the default, but I would like to keep the largest size font to be the default. Please help me out on what I can do? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your terminal.  Find the `Edit` menu at the top.  Then select `Profile Preferences`.  Then at the bottom of the window that pops up, select `Custom font`.  Then you can select your font size as you like, and it should stay the same after reboot.

**EDIT:**

To change the font size of the tty, run this command :

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

You will then go through 4 steps.  In the first step, select `UTF-8`.  In the second step, select `Combined - Latin; Slavic Cyrillic; Greek`.  Then select `Fixed`, and finally you can select your font size.  The default (at least for me) is `8x16`, but you can set it ad libitum.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, however what I means is the console terminal (virtual terminal) which appears when you click 'Ctrl+Alt+F1/ to F6.' What happens is the console will take the font from the terminal, however, am asking about the way to make the virtual console terminal bigger than the font in the terminal on the desktop. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, sorry.  I'll edit my answer.